# Is it possible to format PyCharm Python code inside of parentheses?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've searched for quite a while, and maybe I'm just completely oblivious, but for the life of me I cannot find out how to get any editor to format Python code within brackets, curly braces, or parentheses correctly. I switched over to using PyCharm over VSCode because I couldn't get it figured out there, but now I can't figure it out with PyCharm either...

For example...

```
incorrect_way = [
    'instead_of' = 'this',
    'type_of' = 'newline',
    'indentation' = 'format'
    ]

correct_way = {'i_would_like' : 'something',
               'more_like' : 'this',
               'type_of' : 'newline_format'}

def another_possibility = (
                           'or_possibly' = 'even',
                           'something'   = 'indented',
                           'in_this'     = 'format'
                          )
```

I'm still fairly inexperienced when it comes to python, so please forgive my lack of understanding between the above coding styles. I just know that whatever it is that I seem to be doing is annoying and ugly to look at, so I'd like to begin developing better habits early on before it's too difficult to change my ways later on. Thank you in advance!

[EDIT]

The downvote is entirely unnecessary. The question was adequately posed, the question has not been answered previously, the question was asked to pose a definitive answer, and clearly coded examples were given. This question perfectly adheres to every standard preached about here, but because there is a disagreement with what I call 'incorrect' (which, by the way, should have been apparent after reading the closing statement saying crystal clear that I'm learning still, and even asked to forgive any discrepancies) I get a downvote because of it? So you took the time to get bent out of shape about semantics, yet couldn't take the time to even answer my question? Wow, you guys really make people enjoy the learning process!

Comment: What you are calling "incorrect" is actually a correct way.

Comment: the opening bracket is on the same line as the define.  The list items are one indent level (4 spaces), each on a separate line.  The closing bracket is on the last line, again, indented one level, 4 spaces (or 1 tabs- but not recommended).